# Can interfaces evolve with time?

Tags: java, interface

Interfaces are great from a flexibility standpoint. But in case, where an interface is used by a large number of clients. Adding new methods to the interface while keeping the old mehtods intact will break all clients' code as new methods won't be present in clients. As shown below:

```
public interface CustomInterface {

    public void method1();

}

public class CustomImplementation implements CustomInterface {

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("This is method1");
    }
}
```

If at some point later in time, we add another method to this interface all clients' code will break.

```
public interface CustomInterface {

    public void method1();

    public void method2();

}
```

To avoid this we have to explicitly implement new methods in all clients' code.

So I think of interfaces and this scenario as following:

1. Interfaces once written are like carving in stone. They are rarely supposed, and expected to change. And if they do, they come with a huge cost(rewriting the whole code) which programmers should be ready for.
2. In continuation with the point above, Is it possible to write interfaces that can stand the test of time?
3. How such a scenario is handled in interfaces where you expect additional functionality in future? That is anticipating change in the contract by which all clients are binded.

EDIT: `Default` method is indeed a nice addition to Java Interfaces which a lot of people have mentioned in their answers. But my question was more in the context of code design. And how forcing method implementation on the client is an intrinsic character of an interface. But this contract between an interface and a client seems fragile as functionality will eventually  evolve.

Comment: Reading suggestion: Framework design guidelines (it's .net but it's a good reading for java programmer too) has a section about chosing between class or interface. As stated by other answers they too talk about using classes since they're a lot more flexible than interfaces and let you evolve it without breaking client code.

Answer (score 21):

One solution to this problem was introduced in Java 8 in the form of default methods in interfaces. It allowed to add new methods to existing Java SE interfaces without breaking existing code, since it supplied default implementation to all the new methods.

For example, the `Iterable` interface, which is widely used (it's a super interface of the `Collection` interface) was added two new default methods - `default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)` and `default Spliterator<T> spliterator()`.

Comment: okay, I would look into that. But prior to Java 8 from the design perspective, are interfaces supposed to be immutable? That is once a contract has been made with clients it should not change.

Answer (score 18):

```
public interface CustomInterface {
    public void method1();
}

public interface CustomInterface2 extends CustomInterface {
    public void meathod2();
}
```

Other than default method you can use inheritance property as show above by which new interface will have all previous method along with new methods and use this interface in your required situation.

Comment: But that is not what I am looking for. Because with the code above, client code will still break.

Comment: because method 2 is still unimplemented in client code.

Comment: well In your approach ,lets say we have 25 classes A-Z that implements interface1 and due to some reason u have to add new meathod that would be used only by 5 classes A-E,but not hte rest of the class.So by ur approach u have to implement meathod2 in all classes A-Z,there is not option.But by using Inheritance u can make changes only in the required classes,not the other class.This way u end up saving lot of time.

Answer (score 8):

Java 8 has introduced default implementation for methods. These implementations reside in the interface. If a new method with a default implementation is created in an interface that is already implemented by many classes, there is no need to modify all the classes, but only the ones that we want to have a different implementation for the newly defined method than the default one.

Now, what about older Java versions? Here we can have another interface that extends the first one. After that, classes that we want to implement the newly-declared method will be changed to implement the new interface. As shown below.

```
public interface IFirst {
    void method1();
}

public class ClassOne implements IFirst() {
    public void method1();
}

public class ClassTwo implements IFirst() {
    public void method1();
}
```

Now, we want `method2()` declared, but it should only be implemented by `ClassOne`.

```
public interface ISecond extends iFirst {
    void method2();
}

public class ClassOne implements ISecond() {
    public void method1();
    public void method2();
}

public class ClassTwo implements IFirst() {
    public void method1();
}
```

This approach will be ok in most cases, but it does have downsides as well. For example, we want `method3()` (and only that one) for ClassTwo. We will need a new interface `IThird`. If later we will want to add `method4()` that should be implemented by both ClassOne and ClassTwo, we will need to modify (but not `ClassThree` that also `implemented IFirst`) we will need to change both `ISecond` and `IThird`.

There rarely is a "magic bullet" when it comes to programming. In the case of interfaces, it is best if they don't change. This isn't always the case in real-life situations. That is why it is advised that interfaces offer just "the contract" (must-have functionality) and when possible use abstract classes.

Answer (score 5):

A future interface change shouldn't break anything that has been working -- if it does, it's a different interface. (It may deprecate things, though, and a full cycle after deprecation it may be acceptable to say that throwing an Unimplemented exception is acceptable.)

To add things to an interface, the cleanest answer is to derive a new interface from it. That will allow using objects implementing the new behaviors with code expecting the old ones, while letting the user declare appropriately and/or typecast to get access to the new features. It's a bit annoying since it may require instanceof tests, but it's the most robust approach, and it's the one you'll see in many industry standards.

Answer (score 4):

Interfaces are contracts between the developer and clients, so you're right - they are carved in stone and should not be changed. Therefore, an interface should expose (= demand) only the basic functionality that's absolutely required from a class.

Take the `List` interface for example. There are many implementations of lists in Java, many of which evolve over time (better under-the-hood algorithms, improved memory storage), but the basic "concept" of a list - add an item, search for an item, remove an item - should not and will not ever change.

So, to your question: Instead of writing interfaces which classes implement, you can use **abstract classes**. Interfaces are basically purely-abstract classes, in the sense that they do not provide any built-in functionality. However, one *can* add new, non-abstract methods to an abstract class that clients will not be required to implement (*override*).

Take this abstract class (= interface) for example:

```
abstract class BaseQueue {
    abstract public Object pop();
    abstract public void push(Object o);
    abstract public int length();
    public void clearEven() {};
}

public class MyQueue extends BaseQueue {
    @Override
    public Object pop() { ... }

    ...
}
```

Just like in interfaces, every class that extends `BaseQueue` is contractually bound to implement the abstract methods. The `clearEven()` method, however, is not an abstract method (and already comes with an empty implementation), so the client is not forced to implement it, or even use it.

That means that you can leverage the power of abstract classes in Java in order to create non-contractually-binding methods. You can add other methods to the base class in the future as much as you like, provided that they are not abstract methods.

Comment: This is equivalent to using `default`, except using abstract classes instead of interfaces introduces a whole host of headaches due to Java prohibiting multiple inheritance. But I downvoted this because the empty implementation of clearEven() does in fact violate the actual contract of the method, specifically that it "clears even" (whatever that may be). A better way would be to throw UnsupportedOperationException, but it'd still be a poor practice. BaseQueue <- ClearEvenableQueue inheritance is the clean solution in an OO mindset.

Comment: @SáT Limiting inheritance to a single type is a very rational and useful design principle in OO programming. So I tend to disagree that abstract classes are a headache to implement just because they do not support multiple inheritance. You are comparing interfaces and abstract classes, and that is why you find abstract classes to be less flexible than interfaces. But both have very different purpose in code architecture and should not be compared. Though I agree with your second and third point.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is more about design and techniques, so java8 answers are a bit misleading. This problem was known long before java8, so there are some other solutions for it.

First, there are no absolutely chargeless ways to solve a problem. The size of inconviniences that come from interface evolving depends on how the library is used and how deliberate your design is.

**1)** No techniques will help, if you designed an interface and forgot to include a **mandatory** method in it. Plan your design better and try to anticipate how clients will use your interfaces.
Example: Imagine `Machine` interface that has `turnOn()` method but misses `turnOff()` method. Introducing a new method with default empty implementation in java8 will prevent compilation errors but will not really help, because calling a method will have no effect. Providing working implementation is sometimes impossible because interface has no fields and state.

**2)** Different implementations usually have things in common. Don't be afraid to keep common logic in parent class. Inherit your library classes from this parent class. This will enforce library clients to inherit their own implementations from your parent class as well. Now you can make small changes to the interface without breaking everything.
Example: You decided to include `isTurnedOn()` method to your interface. With a basic class, you can write a default method implementation that would make sence. Classes that were not inherited from parent class still need to provide their own method implementations, but since method is not mandatory, it will be easy for them.

**3)** Upgrading the functionality is usually achieved by extending the interfaces. There's no reason to force library clients to implement a bunch of new methods because they may not need them.
Example: You decided to add `stayIdle()` method to your interface. It makes sence for classes in your library, but not for custom client classes. Since this functionality is new, it's better to create a new interface that will extend `Machine` and use it when it's needed.